# What's the earliest life hook of vue instance that has access to localStorage?

Tags: vue.js

What's the earliest life hook of a vue instance that has access to localStorage and other DOM APIs?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say all of them have access to localStorage, because when Vue takes control `window` (and `window.localStorage`) already exists. So that'd be `beforeCreate`. But you could just try:

```js
Vue.component('test-component', {
  data: function() { return { hello: "Hello World!" }},
  template: '<div>{{ hello }}</div>',
  beforeCreate: function() {console.log("beforeCreate has access to localStorage?", typeof localStorage === "object") },
  created: function() {console.log("Created has access to localStorage?", typeof localStorage === "object") },
  mounted: function() {console.log("Mounted has access to localStorage?", typeof localStorage === "object") },
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test-component />
</div>
```

Looks like SO sandbox doesn't allow accessing `localStorage`. Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/jordinebot/pen/qyoZzK) instead.